# About the expression "sweep a kiss"

Tags: expressions

This expression appears in the song "Achilles Last Stand" of Led Zeppelin and Google displays it in a couple more results. Is this expression about the same as "give a kiss"/"send a kiss"? Is it common somewhere?

Comment: There is no such lyric in the Zep song. The only mention of 'kiss' is in the line "Slipping off a glancing kiss" which is more likely to mean giving someone a brief kiss than actually 'falling off one'.

Comment: listen to the music and see if he sings "Slipping off" or "swept New York" and don't do a cheap google search to contest my question. https://www.angelfire.com/nm/zeppelin/ also, slipping a kiss is even weirder.

Comment: Can't tell on the original - I'll give you it from one live version I can see his lips though. Perhaps you ought to quote the line rather than your own re-cast of it. It would perhaps give something better to hang an answer from. The other problem really is 'poetry/lyrics' don't tend to conform to regular grammar/idiom.

Comment: poetry gives foundation to formal grammar not the other way around and yes, the live version actually cleared all my doubts that the lyrics in that website I presented are 100% correct. Couldn't be "slap" because of the "e" instead of "a", couldn't be "slip" for the same reason. When that expression began is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative meaning for "sweep" is:

> move swiftly and smoothly.

Therefore, it literally just means:

> swiftly give a kiss.

The term "sweep a kiss" is rarely used; thus, it isn't referenced anywhere on dictionaries.

Comment: It's also not referenced at all in the song lyrics ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin I was looking for it too :(

Comment: @Tetsujin "swept New York a glancing kiss"

Comment: @U12-Forward it totally is though, and you can find in Google this expression in some other few results.